# How to compress Bitmap using PNG format?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have a custom View(WorldMapView) and a map drawable(3209x1287,PNG,64-bit color,1.33M) and I am getting

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(148679388bytes) bitmap.

I tried to compress like this.

```
  WorldMapView worldMapView = (WorldMapView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map_of_world);
  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.map)).getBitmap();
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
  Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
  worldMapView.setImageBitmap(decoded);
```

But if you are using PNG format then it will not compress your image because PNG is a lossless format,so can anyone please suggest a solution?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: `But if you are using PNG format then it will not compress your image because PNG is a lossless format` You answered yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to compress like this

You cannot "compress" a `Bitmap` to another `Bitmap`. Images are compressed *on disk* in some file formats (e.g., PNG, JPEG, WebP). A `Bitmap` is *always* uncompressed.

> if you are using PNG format then it will not compress your image because PNG is a lossless format

This is unrelated to your problem. PNG is an on-disk format. `Bitmap` is not. Going from a `Bitmap` to a `Bitmap` will not "compress" the bitmap, no matter what image format you use.

> so can anyone please suggest a solution?

Reduce the resolution of the image by 90% or so.

Or, use a view that handles large images, such as [this one](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view).